# Dictionary with a list as value

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples

I have a list of tuples:

```
res=[(0, 0, 255, 0, 0),(1, 0, 255, 0, 0),(0, 1, 255, 0, 0),(1, 1, 255, 0, 0),
(4, 4, 0, 255, 0),(5, 4, 0, 255, 0),(4, 5, 0, 255, 0),(5, 5, 0, 255, 0)]
```

This is my idea:

```
keys = [l[2:] for l in res]
values = [l[:2] for l in res]
d=dict(zip(keys, values))
```

and this is my output:

```
{(255, 0, 0): (1, 1), (0, 255, 0): (5, 5)}
```

My output is wrong, I need this one:

```
{(255, 0, 0): [(0, 0),(1,0),(0,1),(1,1)], 
(0, 255, 0): [(4,4),(5,4),(4,5),(5,5)]}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The problem with your approach is that duplicate keys are overwritten. You need to write an actual `for` loop which appends to a list (or instantiates a new one) for every key encountered -- i.e. for every key, value pair you iterate over, you need to check if the key is already in your output dictionary. If so, append the current value to the list. If not, add the key to the dictionary and put the current value into a new list there.

Comment: That's a list of tuples, not nested list.

Comment: `defaultdict(list)` or `dict.setdefault([])` will be useful for this.

Comment: @Barmar this is homework so I doubt OP is allowed to do so. It is always beneficial to learn the more basic patterns and algorithms first.

Comment: ok so i need to study these method. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are much more elegant solutions to this problem, but the point of the exercise is (likely) for you to practice logic and control flow, so I'll show a more beginner-appropriate solution:

```py
output = {}
for entry in res:
    key, value = entry[2:], entry[:2]
    if key not in output:
        output[key] = []
    output[key].append(value)
```

As has been mentioned though, `collections.defaultdict(list)` is the prime candidate for a problem like this.

Answer (score 5):

Using [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```py
from collections import defaultdict 

out = defaultdict(list)

for t in res:
    out[t[2:]].append(t[:2])

dict(out)
```

Or with a classical dictionary:

```py
out = {}

for t in res:
    k = t[2:]
    if k not in out:
        out[k] = []
    out[k].append(t[:2])
```

Output:

```
{(255, 0, 0): [(0, 0), (1, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1)],
 (0, 255, 0): [(4, 4), (5, 4), (4, 5), (5, 5)]}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use a dictionary with `.setdefault()` to accumulate the results, using slicing to generate the appropriate keys and values.

```py
ans = {}

for entry in res:
    ans.setdefault(entry[2:], []).append(entry[:2])
    
print(ans)
```

This outputs:

```py
{
 (255, 0, 0): [(0, 0), (1, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1)],
 (0, 255, 0): [(4, 4), (5, 4), (4, 5), (5, 5)]
}
```